# Viewport Runs Extremely Slow

Tags: 3d-view

Hey folks been using blender for a couple months using the program for me is really slow. I've been looking for the solution. Just every time I enabled botaniq, scatter 5, truevfx its makes blender almost unusable. The scenes I'm doing are small nothing to large - small closeup scenes.

EDIT>PREFERENCES
cuda
For cuda have graphics card selected only
optiX
For cuda have graphics card selected only

CPU: Processor  11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11900K @ 3.50GHz, 3504 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s)
Installed Physical Memory (RAM) 32.0 GB
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050
3440x1440 monitor

```
System information
====================================
= Blender 3.2.1 System Information =
====================================
Blender:
====================================

version: 3.2.1, branch: master, commit date: 2022-07-05 15:44, hash: a2d59b2dac9e, type: release
build date: 2022-07-06, 07:45:50
platform: 'Windows-10-10.0.22000-SP0'
binary path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\blender.exe'
build cflags: /W3 /w34062 /w34115 /w34189 /wd4018 /wd4146 /wd4065 /wd4127 /wd4181 /wd4200 /wd4244 /wd4267 /wd4305 /wd4800 /wd4828 /wd4996 /wd4661 /we4013 /we4133 /we4431 /w35038 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /nologo /J /Gd /MP /bigobj /Zc:inline -openmp   
build cxxflags: /W3 /w34062 /w34115 /w34189 /wd4018 /wd4146 /wd4065 /wd4127 /wd4181 /wd4200 /wd4244 /wd4267 /wd4305 /wd4800 /wd4828 /wd4996 /wd4661 /we4013 /we4133 /we4431 /w35038 /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /EHsc /nologo /J /Gd /MP /EHsc /bigobj /Zc:inline /permissive- /Zc:twoPhase- -openmp /Zc:__cplusplus   
build linkflags: /MACHINE:X64  /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /STACK:2097152 /ignore:4049 /ignore:4217 /ignore:4221
build system: CMake

Python:
====================================

version: 3.10.2 (main, Jan 27 2022, 08:34:43) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
file system encoding: utf-8:surrogatepass
paths:
    'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\scripts\\addons\\True-Terrain LITE\\internal_modules'
    'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\scripts\\addons\\blenderkit\\dependencies\\Fallback'
    'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\scripts\\addons\\blenderkit\\dependencies\\Windows'
    'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\scripts\\addons\\blenderkit\\daemon'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\scripts\\startup'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\scripts\\modules'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\python310.zip'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\python\\DLLs'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\python\\lib'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\python\\bin'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\python'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\python\\lib\\site-packages'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\scripts\\freestyle\\modules'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\scripts\\addons\\modules'
    'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\scripts\\addons\\modules'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\scripts\\addons'
    'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\scripts\\addons'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\scripts\\addons_contrib'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\scripts\\startup\\bl_ui'
    'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\site-packages'

Python (External Binary):
====================================

binary path: 'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\python\\bin\\python.EXE'
version: Python 3.10.2

Directories:
====================================

scripts:
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\scripts\\modules'
    'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender 3.2\\3.2\\scripts'
    'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\scripts'
user scripts: 'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\scripts'
pref scripts: None
datafiles: 'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\datafiles'
config: 'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\config'
scripts : 'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\scripts'
autosave: 'C:\\Users\\\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\3.2\\autosave'
tempdir: 'C:\\Users\\JOSEPH~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\blender_a15236\\'

FFmpeg:
====================================

avcodec:   '59, 18, 100'
avdevice:  '59,  4, 100'
avformat:  '59, 16, 100'
avutil:    '57, 17, 100'
swscale:   ' 6,  4, 100'

SDL:
====================================

Version: 2.0.20
Loading method: linked (WITH_SDL_DYNLOAD=OFF)

Other Libraries:
====================================

OpenColorIO:  2,  1,  1
OpenImageIO:  2,  3, 13
OpenShadingLanguage:  1, 11, 17
OpenSubdiv:  0,  0,  0
OpenVDB:  9,  0,  0
Alembic:  1,  8,  3
USD:  0, 22,  3

GPU:
====================================

renderer:   'NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050/PCIe/SSE2'
vendor:     'NVIDIA Corporation'
version:    '4.5.0 NVIDIA 516.59'
extensions:
    GL_AMD_multi_draw_indirect
    GL_AMD_seamless_cubemap_per_texture
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_layer
    GL_AMD_vertex_shader_viewport_index
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility
    GL_ARB_ES3_1_compatibility
    GL_ARB_ES3_2_compatibility
    GL_ARB_ES3_compatibility
    GL_ARB_arrays_of_arrays
    GL_ARB_base_instance
    GL_ARB_bindless_texture
    GL_ARB_blend_func_extended
    GL_ARB_buffer_storage
    GL_ARB_clear_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_clear_texture
    GL_ARB_clip_control
    GL_ARB_color_buffer_float
    GL_ARB_compressed_texture_pixel_storage
    GL_ARB_compute_shader
    GL_ARB_compute_variable_group_size
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted
    GL_ARB_conservative_depth
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer
    GL_ARB_copy_image
    GL_ARB_cull_distance
    GL_ARB_debug_output
    GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float
    GL_ARB_depth_clamp
    GL_ARB_depth_texture
    GL_ARB_derivative_control
    GL_ARB_direct_state_access
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers
    GL_ARB_draw_buffers_blend
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex
    GL_ARB_draw_indirect
    GL_ARB_draw_instanced
    GL_ARB_enhanced_layouts
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location
    GL_ARB_explicit_uniform_location
    GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions
    GL_ARB_fragment_layer_viewport
    GL_ARB_fragment_program
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader
    GL_ARB_fragment_shader_interlock
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_object
    GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB
    GL_ARB_geometry_shader4
    GL_ARB_get_program_binary
    GL_ARB_get_texture_sub_image
    GL_ARB_gl_spirv
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader5
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64
    GL_ARB_gpu_shader_int64
    GL_ARB_half_float_pixel
    GL_ARB_half_float_vertex
    GL_ARB_imaging
    GL_ARB_indirect_parameters
    GL_ARB_instanced_arrays
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query
    GL_ARB_internalformat_query2
    GL_ARB_invalidate_subdata
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_alignment
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range
    GL_ARB_multi_bind
    GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect
    GL_ARB_multisample
    GL_ARB_multitexture
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query2
    GL_ARB_parallel_shader_compile
    GL_ARB_pipeline_statistics_query
    GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_point_parameters
    GL_ARB_point_sprite
    GL_ARB_polygon_offset_clamp
    GL_ARB_post_depth_coverage
    GL_ARB_program_interface_query
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex
    GL_ARB_query_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_robust_buffer_access_behavior
    GL_ARB_robustness
    GL_ARB_sample_locations
    GL_ARB_sample_shading
    GL_ARB_sampler_objects
    GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map
    GL_ARB_seamless_cubemap_per_texture
    GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counter_ops
    GL_ARB_shader_atomic_counters
    GL_ARB_shader_ballot
    GL_ARB_shader_bit_encoding
    GL_ARB_shader_clock
    GL_ARB_shader_draw_parameters
    GL_ARB_shader_group_vote
    GL_ARB_shader_image_load_store
    GL_ARB_shader_image_size
    GL_ARB_shader_objects
    GL_ARB_shader_precision
    GL_ARB_shader_storage_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_shader_subroutine
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_image_samples
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod
    GL_ARB_shader_viewport_layer_array
    GL_ARB_shading_language_100
    GL_ARB_shading_language_420pack
    GL_ARB_shading_language_include
    GL_ARB_shading_language_packing
    GL_ARB_shadow
    GL_ARB_sparse_buffer
    GL_ARB_sparse_texture
    GL_ARB_sparse_texture2
    GL_ARB_sparse_texture_clamp
    GL_ARB_spirv_extensions
    GL_ARB_stencil_texturing
    GL_ARB_sync
    GL_ARB_tessellation_shader
    GL_ARB_texture_barrier
    GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_object_rgb32
    GL_ARB_texture_buffer_range
    GL_ARB_texture_compression
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_bptc
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map_array
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3
    GL_ARB_texture_filter_anisotropic
    GL_ARB_texture_filter_minmax
    GL_ARB_texture_float
    GL_ARB_texture_gather
    GL_ARB_texture_mirror_clamp_to_edge
    GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat
    GL_ARB_texture_multisample
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two
    GL_ARB_texture_query_levels
    GL_ARB_texture_query_lod
    GL_ARB_texture_rectangle
    GL_ARB_texture_rg
    GL_ARB_texture_rgb10_a2ui
    GL_ARB_texture_stencil8
    GL_ARB_texture_storage
    GL_ARB_texture_storage_multisample
    GL_ARB_texture_swizzle
    GL_ARB_texture_view
    GL_ARB_timer_query
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback2
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback3
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_instanced
    GL_ARB_transform_feedback_overflow_query
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix
    GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit
    GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_binding
    GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object
    GL_ARB_vertex_program
    GL_ARB_vertex_shader
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_10f_11f_11f_rev
    GL_ARB_vertex_type_2_10_10_10_rev
    GL_ARB_viewport_array
    GL_ARB_window_pos
    GL_ATI_draw_buffers
    GL_ATI_texture_float
    GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once
    GL_EXTX_framebuffer_mixed_formats
    GL_EXT_Cg_shader
    GL_EXT_abgr
    GL_EXT_bgra
    GL_EXT_bindable_uniform
    GL_EXT_blend_color
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax
    GL_EXT_blend_subtract
    GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array
    GL_EXT_depth_bounds_test
    GL_EXT_direct_state_access
    GL_EXT_draw_buffers2
    GL_EXT_draw_instanced
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements
    GL_EXT_fog_coord
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample_blit_scaled
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_object
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
    GL_EXT_geometry_shader4
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters
    GL_EXT_gpu_shader4
    GL_EXT_import_sync_object
    GL_EXT_memory_object
    GL_EXT_memory_object_win32
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays
    GL_EXT_multiview_texture_multisample
    GL_EXT_multiview_timer_query
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil
    GL_EXT_packed_float
    GL_EXT_packed_pixels
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object
    GL_EXT_point_parameters
    GL_EXT_polygon_offset_clamp
    GL_EXT_post_depth_coverage
    GL_EXT_provoking_vertex
    GL_EXT_raster_multisample
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal
    GL_EXT_secondary_color
    GL_EXT_semaphore
    GL_EXT_semaphore_win32
    GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color
    GL_EXT_shader_image_load_formatted
    GL_EXT_shader_image_load_store
    GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix
    GL_EXT_shadow_funcs
    GL_EXT_sparse_texture2
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side
    GL_EXT_stencil_wrap
    GL_EXT_texture3D
    GL_EXT_texture_array
    GL_EXT_texture_buffer_object
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_dxt1
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_latc
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc
    GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc
    GL_EXT_texture_cube_map
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp
    GL_EXT_texture_env_add
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_minmax
    GL_EXT_texture_integer
    GL_EXT_texture_lod
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias
    GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp
    GL_EXT_texture_object
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_R8
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode
    GL_EXT_texture_shadow_lod
    GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent
    GL_EXT_texture_storage
    GL_EXT_texture_swizzle
    GL_EXT_timer_query
    GL_EXT_transform_feedback2
    GL_EXT_vertex_array
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra
    GL_EXT_vertex_attrib_64bit
    GL_EXT_win32_keyed_mutex
    GL_EXT_window_rectangles
    GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip
    GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat
    GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced
    GL_KHR_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
    GL_KHR_context_flush_control
    GL_KHR_debug
    GL_KHR_no_error
    GL_KHR_parallel_shader_compile
    GL_KHR_robust_buffer_access_behavior
    GL_KHR_robustness
    GL_KHR_shader_subgroup
    GL_KTX_buffer_region
    GL_NVX_blend_equation_advanced_multi_draw_buffers
    GL_NVX_conditional_render
    GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info
    GL_NVX_gpu_multicast2
    GL_NVX_linked_gpu_multicast
    GL_NVX_multigpu_info
    GL_NVX_nvenc_interop
    GL_NVX_progress_fence
    GL_NV_ES1_1_compatibility
    GL_NV_ES3_1_compatibility
    GL_NV_alpha_to_coverage_dither_control
    GL_NV_bindless_multi_draw_indirect
    GL_NV_bindless_multi_draw_indirect_count
    GL_NV_bindless_texture
    GL_NV_blend_equation_advanced
    GL_NV_blend_equation_advanced_coherent
    GL_NV_blend_minmax_factor
    GL_NV_blend_square
    GL_NV_clip_space_w_scaling
    GL_NV_command_list
    GL_NV_compute_program5
    GL_NV_compute_shader_derivatives
    GL_NV_conditional_render
    GL_NV_conservative_raster
    GL_NV_conservative_raster_dilate
    GL_NV_conservative_raster_pre_snap
    GL_NV_conservative_raster_pre_snap_triangles
    GL_NV_conservative_raster_underestimation
    GL_NV_copy_depth_to_color
    GL_NV_copy_image
    GL_NV_depth_buffer_float
    GL_NV_depth_clamp
    GL_NV_draw_texture
    GL_NV_draw_vulkan_image
    GL_NV_explicit_multisample
    GL_NV_feature_query
    GL_NV_fence
    GL_NV_fill_rectangle
    GL_NV_float_buffer
    GL_NV_fog_distance
    GL_NV_fragment_coverage_to_color
    GL_NV_fragment_program
    GL_NV_fragment_program2
    GL_NV_fragment_program_option
    GL_NV_fragment_shader_barycentric
    GL_NV_fragment_shader_interlock
    GL_NV_framebuffer_mixed_samples
    GL_NV_framebuffer_multisample_coverage
    GL_NV_geometry_shader4
    GL_NV_geometry_shader_passthrough
    GL_NV_gpu_multicast
    GL_NV_gpu_program4
    GL_NV_gpu_program4_1
    GL_NV_gpu_program5
    GL_NV_gpu_program5_mem_extended
    GL_NV_gpu_program_fp64
    GL_NV_gpu_shader5
    GL_NV_half_float
    GL_NV_internalformat_sample_query
    GL_NV_light_max_exponent
    GL_NV_memory_attachment
    GL_NV_memory_object_sparse
    GL_NV_mesh_shader
    GL_NV_multisample_coverage
    GL_NV_multisample_filter_hint
    GL_NV_occlusion_query
    GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2
    GL_NV_path_rendering
    GL_NV_path_rendering_shared_edge
    GL_NV_pixel_data_range
    GL_NV_point_sprite
    GL_NV_primitive_restart
    GL_NV_primitive_shading_rate
    GL_NV_query_resource
    GL_NV_query_resource_tag
    GL_NV_register_combiners
    GL_NV_register_combiners2
    GL_NV_representative_fragment_test
    GL_NV_sample_locations
    GL_NV_sample_mask_override_coverage
    GL_NV_scissor_exclusive
    GL_NV_shader_atomic_counters
    GL_NV_shader_atomic_float
    GL_NV_shader_atomic_float64
    GL_NV_shader_atomic_fp16_vector
    GL_NV_shader_atomic_int64
    GL_NV_shader_buffer_load
    GL_NV_shader_storage_buffer_object
    GL_NV_shader_subgroup_partitioned
    GL_NV_shader_texture_footprint
    GL_NV_shader_thread_group
    GL_NV_shader_thread_shuffle
    GL_NV_shading_rate_image
    GL_NV_stereo_view_rendering
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection
    GL_NV_texture_barrier
    GL_NV_texture_compression_vtc
    GL_NV_texture_dirty_tile_map
    GL_NV_texture_env_combine4
    GL_NV_texture_multisample
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle_compressed
    GL_NV_texture_shader
    GL_NV_texture_shader2
    GL_NV_texture_shader3
    GL_NV_timeline_semaphore
    GL_NV_transform_feedback
    GL_NV_transform_feedback2
    GL_NV_uniform_buffer_unified_memory
    GL_NV_vertex_array_range
    GL_NV_vertex_array_range2
    GL_NV_vertex_attrib_integer_64bit
    GL_NV_vertex_buffer_unified_memory
    GL_NV_vertex_program
    GL_NV_vertex_program1_1
    GL_NV_vertex_program2
    GL_NV_vertex_program2_option
    GL_NV_vertex_program3
    GL_NV_viewport_array2
    GL_NV_viewport_swizzle
    GL_OVR_multiview
    GL_OVR_multiview2
    GL_S3_s3tc
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod
    GL_SGIX_depth_texture
    GL_SGIX_shadow
    GL_SUN_slice_accum
    GL_WIN_swap_hint
    WGL_EXT_swap_control

Implementation Dependent GPU Limits:
====================================

Maximum Batch Vertices: 1048576
Maximum Batch Indices:  1048576

GLSL:
Maximum Varying Floats: 124
Maximum Vertex Attributes:  16
Maximum Vertex Uniform Components:  4096
Maximum Fragment Uniform Components:    4096
Maximum Vertex Image Units: 32
Maximum Fragment Image Units:   32
Maximum Pipeline Image Units:   192

Cycles:
====================================


CPU device capabilities: SSE2 SSE3 SSE41 AVX AVX2

CUDA device capabilities:
    NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_THREADS_PER_BLOCK           1024
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_BLOCK_DIM_X         1024
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_BLOCK_DIM_Y         1024
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_BLOCK_DIM_Z         64
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_GRID_DIM_X          2147483647
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_GRID_DIM_Y          65535
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_GRID_DIM_Z          65535
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_SHARED_MEMORY_PER_BLOCK         49152
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SHARED_MEMORY_PER_BLOCK         49152
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_TOTAL_CONSTANT_MEMORY           65536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_WARP_SIZE           32
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_PITCH           2147483647
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_REGISTERS_PER_BLOCK         65536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_REGISTERS_PER_BLOCK         65536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_CLOCK_RATE          1845000
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE_ALIGNMENT           512
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_GPU_OVERLAP         1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT            20
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_KERNEL_EXEC_TIMEOUT         0
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_INTEGRATED          0
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_CAN_MAP_HOST_MEMORY         1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPUTE_MODE            0
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_WIDTH         131072
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_WIDTH         131072
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_HEIGHT            65536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_WIDTH         16384
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_HEIGHT            16384
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_DEPTH         16384
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LAYERED_WIDTH         32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LAYERED_HEIGHT            32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LAYERED_LAYERS            2048
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_ARRAY_WIDTH           32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_ARRAY_HEIGHT          32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_ARRAY_NUMSLICES           2048
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_SURFACE_ALIGNMENT           512
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_CONCURRENT_KERNELS          1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_ECC_ENABLED         0
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_TCC_DRIVER          0
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MEMORY_CLOCK_RATE           7001000
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_GLOBAL_MEMORY_BUS_WIDTH         128
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_L2_CACHE_SIZE           1572864
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_THREADS_PER_MULTIPROCESSOR          1536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_ASYNC_ENGINE_COUNT          1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_UNIFIED_ADDRESSING          1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_LAYERED_WIDTH         32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_LAYERED_LAYERS            2048
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_CAN_TEX2D_GATHER            1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_GATHER_WIDTH          32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_GATHER_HEIGHT         32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_WIDTH_ALTERNATE           8192
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_HEIGHT_ALTERNATE          8192
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE3D_DEPTH_ALTERNATE           32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE_PITCH_ALIGNMENT         32
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURECUBEMAP_WIDTH            32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURECUBEMAP_LAYERED_WIDTH            32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURECUBEMAP_LAYERED_LAYERS           2046
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE1D_WIDTH         32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_WIDTH         131072
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_HEIGHT            65536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE3D_WIDTH         16384
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE3D_HEIGHT            16384
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE3D_DEPTH         16384
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE1D_LAYERED_WIDTH         32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE1D_LAYERED_LAYERS            2048
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_LAYERED_WIDTH         32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_LAYERED_HEIGHT            32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACE2D_LAYERED_LAYERS            2048
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACECUBEMAP_WIDTH            32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACECUBEMAP_LAYERED_WIDTH            32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_SURFACECUBEMAP_LAYERED_LAYERS           2046
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_LINEAR_WIDTH          268435456
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LINEAR_WIDTH          131072
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LINEAR_HEIGHT         65000
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_LINEAR_PITCH          2097120
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_MIPMAPPED_WIDTH           32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE2D_MIPMAPPED_HEIGHT          32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY_MAJOR            8
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_COMPUTE_CAPABILITY_MINOR            6
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAXIMUM_TEXTURE1D_MIPMAPPED_WIDTH           32768
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_STREAM_PRIORITIES_SUPPORTED         1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_GLOBAL_L1_CACHE_SUPPORTED           1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_LOCAL_L1_CACHE_SUPPORTED            1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_SHARED_MEMORY_PER_MULTIPROCESSOR            102400
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MAX_REGISTERS_PER_MULTIPROCESSOR            65536
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MANAGED_MEMORY          1
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MULTI_GPU_BOARD         0
        CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MULTI_GPU_BOARD_GROUP_ID            0


Enabled add-ons:
====================================

io_anim_bvh (version: (1, 0, 1), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_anim_bvh\__init__.py)
io_curve_svg (version: (), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_curve_svg\__init__.py)
io_mesh_ply (version: (2, 2, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_mesh_ply\__init__.py)
io_mesh_stl (version: (1, 1, 3), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_mesh_stl\__init__.py)
io_mesh_uv_layout (version: (1, 1, 1), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_mesh_uv_layout\__init__.py)
io_scene_fbx (version: (4, 36, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\__init__.py)
io_scene_gltf2 (version: (3, 2, 43), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_gltf2\__init__.py)
io_scene_obj (version: (3, 9, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\__init__.py)
io_scene_x3d (version: (2, 3, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\io_scene_x3d\__init__.py)
cycles (version: (), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\cycles\__init__.py)
pose_library (version: (2, 0), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\pose_library\__init__.py)
physical-starlight-atmosphere (version: (1, 5, 1), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\physical-starlight-atmosphere\__init__.py)
Scatter5 (version: (5, 2, 0), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\Scatter5\__init__.py)
add_curve_extra_objects (version: (0, 1, 5), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\add_curve_extra_objects\__init__.py)
ant_landscape (version: (0, 1, 8), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\ant_landscape\__init__.py)
BY-GEN (version: (0, 7, 0), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\BY-GEN\__init__.py)
weatherfxinstall2_9 (version: (1, 0), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\weatherfxinstall2_9\__init__.py)
blenderkit (version: (3, 1, 5), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\blenderkit\__init__.py)
botaniq_full (version: (6, 5, 0), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\botaniq_full\__init__.py)
CarlsPhysicsHelper (version: (1, 7, 42), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\CarlsPhysicsHelper.py)
simple-tabs (version: (1, 1, 8), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\simple-tabs\__init__.py)
SliceandDice (version: (1, 1), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\SliceandDice.py)
qz21_2 (version: (2, 1, 3), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\qz21_2\__init__.py)
True-Sky (version: (1,), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\True-Sky\__init__.py)
SimplifyUltra_02 (version: (0, 2), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\SimplifyUltra_02.py)
True-Terrain LITE (version: (4, 3, 2), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\True-Terrain LITE\__init__.py)
URBANIAC (version: (2, 3, 0), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\URBANIAC\__init__.py)
blender_neoner (version: (1, 1, 2), path: C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\blender_neoner\__init__.py)
lighting_dynamic_sky (version: (1, 0, 6), path: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\addons\lighting_dynamic_sky.py)
```

Comment: Are complex scene or simple scene also causing the problem? Try disabling addon one by one until the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Blenderkit  addon and found out it was my firewall blocking the daemon service connection, so it may be not your case but check your firewall or antivirus and allow all services activities named blender or addon related.

Best :)